# How to restrict apache to not send any csv,txt,log,sh file in response

Tags: regex, apache, configuration

What I want here is that, if I create any csv,log,txt,sh file in public or any other folder inside /var/www/ and forgot to remove/delete it, and if any attacker hits the valid file path or url then apache should not send that csv,log,txt or sh file in reponse.

I changed my **apache2.conf** as below but still when I hit URL like

**mysite.com/website_content/assets/transactions.csv**

It sends me the file in response. And I can download it.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(csv|sh|log|txt)$">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

I want apache to not send any file of csv,docx,doc,sh,log,txt in response. any help would make my life easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team leader solved this issue efficiently as

```
<Files ~ "\.csv$">
     Order allow,deny
     Deny from all
</Files>
```

And then I changed into this one to block multiple files as

```
<Files ~ "\.(csv|sh|txt|doc|docx|zip|gz|bz|py|xlsx|db|pdf|crt|info|key|rb)$">
     Order allow,deny
     Deny from all
</Files>
```

There will be 403 Forbidden whenever anyone tries to access such type of files.